# NSInternalInconsistencyException uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to delete the row from UITableView

```
-(void) closePickerViewRow:(id) sender {

    if(self.pickerIsShown && [self.forecastsData count] > 0){

      [self.tableView beginUpdates];
      NSMutableArray* tempArray = [self.forecastsData mutableCopy];
      NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
      self.forecastsData = [tempArray copy];
      [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

But I have an error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason:'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. 
The number of rows  contained in an existing section after the update (11) 
must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the 
update(11),plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that 
section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into 
or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

I'm update the DataSource self.forecastData, and it has 10 elements after deleting the row (11 at start). So, the number of elements is right. Where can be the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes a difference, but whenever I've used `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`, I remove the object from my dataset *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the data *before* telling the tableview:

```
[tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
self.forecastsData = [tempArray copy];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```